# Python unable to translate

Tags: python, string, encoding

I would like to replace all occurrences of some chars with some other and I wrote a translation like as follows:

```
from string import punctuation, maketrans, digits
lower = maketrans("ĞÜŞİÖÇ".encode('utf-8'), "ğüşiöç".encode('utf-8'))
```

-*- coding: UTF-8 -*-' in the beginning of my code.
When I try to encode or decode, I get 'UnicodeDecodeError' and when I do not make any encoding I get an error like

```
ValueError: maketrans arguments must have same length
```

When Python gets these I guess they allocate different size of bytes and length of sequences are not same.
I am using Python 2.7.

Thanks all :)

Answer (score 0):

The `maketrans` method (`bytes.maketrans` in Python 3) operates on `bytes` objects, hence the need to encode the strings.

However, in unicode, characters do not have a fixed length, which can vary between two and four bytes. Here are the two strings, once encoded:

```
>>> "ĞÜŞİÖÇ".encode('utf-8')
b'\xc4\x9e\xc3\x9c\xc5\x9e\xc4\xb0\xc3\x96\xc3\x87'
>>> "ğüşiöç".encode('utf-8')
b'\xc4\x9f\xc3\xbc\xc5\x9fi\xc3\xb6\xc3\xa7'
```

Which explains the `ValueError` you get.

I believe that the right function to call, rather than `bytes.maketrans`, is `str.maketrans`. This function directly operates on strings, which do not need to (and should not) be encoded:

```
>>> str.maketrans("ĞÜŞİÖÇ", "ğüşiöç")
{286: 287, 220: 252, 350: 351, 304: 105, 214: 246, 199: 231}
```

However, these two strings use unicode characters, so your file needs to be encoded in `utf-8`. Therefore, keep `# -- coding: UTF-8 --` at the beginning of your file.